# What do you call the equipment at the end of a crane?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What's the red thing at the end called? There's a hook at the end of the red thing too, but I am assuming the whole thing must have some kind of name. Is there a generic name if not is there a more specific name to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the hook block

[image]

Image from [cranecrews.com](https://www.cranecrews.com/crane-blog/tower-crane-anatomy)